# Where is the origin of the sensor coordinate system?

Tags: android

The documentation shows the orientation of the Axes:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html

But it doesn't specify where exactly the origin is located. Is it in the lower left corner or in the middle of the screen?

The same question also applies to getRotationMatrix:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix(float[], float[], float[], float[])

Since it is a rotation matrix it is implied that the worlds coordinate system has the origin at the same location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the lower left corner of the visible part.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link to any documentation that confirms this?